# Right way to use "using" in C#

Tags: c#

I have two sets of code as below. My question is do we need to use "using" for command and adapter too or just for connection? What is the right way to do this?

```
 using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(ProcedureName)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Connection = conn
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Id, ParameterDirection.Input));
        command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CUR_OUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));

        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
    }
```

The above code has only one using but the below code have 3 using statements

```
 using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        using (OracleCommand oCommand = new OracleCommand(ProcedureName))
        {
            oCommand.BindByName = true;
            oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oCommand.CommandTimeout = await GetCommandTimeout(DatabaseConstants.OracleCommandTimeoutInSeconds);
            oCommand.Connection = conn;

            oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ID", OracleDbType.Varchar2, Id, ParameterDirection.Input));
            oCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("CUR_OUT", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
            using (OracleDataAdapter oDatAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oCommand))
            {
                oDatAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can apply the using on anything that implements the IDisposable interface, which is basically a wrapper of try-finally statements

Comment: The more the better.

Comment: You can use using, or you can explicitly call dispose. using is safer because then you can't forget a path that disposes. it also looks better. what using actually does it inserts a try-catch-finally block, with an empty catch block where it calls dispose in the finally block. not all idispoable objects need to be disposed of. for example a `SqlConnection` is safe to just close and then let it run out of scope. disposing prevents reopening it on top of closing it and that's the only difference. Again it is safer to use using, so you can't forget about closing the connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need them for both - connection and comment. Anything that implements IDisposable should be disposed.

You do NOT need to open the connection before creating the command. This means you can skip one set of {}

```
using (for connection)
using (for command)
{
processing
}
```

This is a lot nicer, easier formatting wise.

I would actually check about adding that using also for the adapter right there at the start.

Also note that in CURRENT C# (8.0 at the time of this writing) you can use using for variable declarations

```
using var conn = new OracleConnection()
```

without (). The variables are disposed at the end. That means even less formatting. This is called a "using declation" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using

Comment: regarding skipping the {}, I think it's wise to always write them out and be explicit about it. but that's a style question that everyone has to find an answer to themselves/use company regulations

Comment: Not always. I often use the using using using one line after the next because if you ahve 7-8 using wiith {} and lines that gets BRUTALLY confusing - too many indentations.

Comment: @TomTom Do I need it for adapter too ?

Comment: @Chatra Does it implement IDisposable?  Then yes.

Comment: in vb you can make lists of idisposable objects after the using directive. that way you avoid the many indents. of course this only works when followup objects don't require one higher up for the CTOR. also even when omitting {} you should indent. not sure if c# allows something similar. either way, the using declaration seems to be a good idea, dispose when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @TomTom I don't see dataadapert implementing IDisposable here. Am I missing anyting ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter?view=netframework-4.8I

Comment: @Chatra The DataAdapter inherits from Component, which implements IDisposable.

Comment: @LarsTech What component? Is there any link?

Comment: He means Component. Which is a class. The link? YOU gave us the link. Heck, look at the inheritance hierarchy in there -besides being obsolete, the class goes through System.ComponentModel.Component.

Comment: @TomTom Thanks tom, It didn't strike me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `using` with all objects that implement IDisposable interface:

- if the objects are managed by the .net framework so that would be an explicit call to destroy them after you have finished using them.
- if they are not managed by the .net frame word that would be your way de dispose of them.